# Java DateUtils print the wrong date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm using java [DateUtils](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Checksifacalendardateistoday.htm) class

```
public boolean checkDate(String dateInString, String format){
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(dateInString);
        system.out.print(date);
        if (DateUtils.isToday(date)) {
           return true;            
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this params:

```
//needs to be true - today's date
boolean boola = checkDate("03/03/2016", "dd/mm/yyyy");
//needs to be true as well - today's date
boolean boolb = checkDate("03/03/2016", "DD/MM/YYYY");
system.out.print(boola); // prints false
system.out.print(boolb); // prints false
```

Here is the console log:

```
sun dec 27 00:00:00 IST 2015 //2015?
sun jan 03 00:03:00 IST 2016 // 03 03 are for dd/mm, DD/MM why they appear in the wrong place?
false
false
```

I have no idea what causing this error, I'm using this function to compare dates.

Comment: The month needs to be specified with capital `M`: `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: Use a debugger to find where it goes wrong and have a look at the documentation of SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and check your strings.

D   Day in year     Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09

Technically, both your strings are wrong, I believe you want `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake on the format string:

- dd: is the day of the month
- MM: is the month of the year
- yyyy: is the year
- mm: is the minutes in the hour
- YYYY: is the Week year

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score -2):

Use **calendar** to check:

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

Date today = c.getTime();